# Next, supabase, vercel - vercel drops supabase connection

Tags: next.js, psql, vercel, supabase

For the last month, at least once every day, Vercel has dropped the connection to supabase.

The Supabase 'support' people say it has nothing to do with supabase (the error is 'user not found - and the auth tool is supabase/auth).

The Vercel logs error message is:

> ```
> Error: No user found
>     at addFeed (/var/task/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:5439:22)
>     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
>     at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/app-render/action-handler.js:284:35
>     at async handleAction (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/app-render/action-handler.js:186:13)
>     at async wrappedRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/app-render/app-render.js:1052:37)
>     at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1153:26)
>     at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache
> ```
>
> (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1300:28)
> at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:99:36

I can submit a form 20ish times, before I get this error for about 10 minutes. If I wait 10 minutes and try to press the same button as I pressed to generate this error, it submits successfully to supabase.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? It's next form actions rather than rest.

**KHB - response**

Thank you for the caching doc link - i'll read that tonight - i haven't seen it before you flagged it, so maybe that is the source of the issue. i'll look into that tonight.

DB connection:

```
export const addFeed = async (data: TCombinedFeedForm) => {
  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();


  if (!user) throw new Error("No user found");

  console.log("Attempting to add feed", data.title, data.published);
```

const format = data.format ? typeof data.format === "string" ? undefined : data.format : undefined;
const regionId = data.regionId ? typeof data.regionId === "string" ? undefined : data.regionId : undefined;

try {
const {industries, practices, themes, organisations, relatedMaterials, ...rest} = data;

```
const adjustedData = {
  ...rest,

  format: format?.value,
  regionId: regionId?.value,
  created_by: user.id,
};

console.log(adjustedData)

const {data: FeedRes, error: FeedError}: SupabaseResponse<CombinedFeedType> = await supabase
  .from("feeds")

  .insert(adjustedData)
  .select();

if (FeedError || !FeedRes) throw new Error(FeedError.message);
```

I am using vercel and supabase with nextjs 13.4 (server actions) and the db connection on supabase is via a vercel connection.

I think I originally made the app as create-next-app with supabase (using the template on the supabase docs site).

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling caching is set up funky in your app.

just error debugging backwards it looks like the error starts when the nextjs cache is hit and the entry misses, but it's already searching within 'some cached object' (`cacheEntry`) and not finding your user. I don't see where supabase is called out to after the cache miss, unless it happens on `app/dashboard/page` after this stack trace.

also a bit more context on how you're implementing the solution to connect to your database would help.

- did you utilize the "integrations" for vercel/supabase? or `create-next-app --with-supabase`
- are you sending commands via `@supabase` library on your server or utilizing fetch to a supabase endpoint?
- are you using `nextjs13` and the recommended [caching logic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching)?

it seems as though [this article](https://vercel.com/guides/connection-pooling-with-serverless-functions) may help with understanding why the serverless functions to third party endpoints go cold and how to work around it. and maybe [this one](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating) can assist with setting up the caching logic you need

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll read about the caching point tonight - I hadn't considered it before now. I'll try to see if I can adapt to that aspect.